# Using Git filter-branch to rename author and committer of several branches including tags

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I need to update all my previous commits to reflect a change in my user-name.

This needs to be done to all branches and also carry through all my tags. I'm the only committer and this is all done in my local repo only.

Using numerous sources on here I arrived at the command

```
git filter-branch --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='new_name'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='new_name';" --tag-name-filter cat -f -- --all
```

which seemed to do the trick, but

```
git log --all --graph
```

shows that instead of overwriting I now have a bunch more branches...

Am I missing something from my above snippet or do I also need to run some form of clean-up command as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the backup copies in `refs/original`, you can easily delete those with the command you find on the help page of `git-filter-branch`: `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d`